# Am I allowed to modify CameraSource.Builder of Android vision package?

Tags: licensing, license-compatibility, license-recommendation, apache-2.0, free-software-definition

I am trying to build my custom library for eye detection, tracking, blinking, smile etc. I am using below open samples instead of reinventing the wheel.

[GooglyEyesActivity](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/blob/master/visionSamples/googly-eyes/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/vision/face/googlyeyes/GooglyEyesActivity.java)

[CameraSource](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/blob/master/visionSamples/barcode-reader/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/vision/barcodereader/ui/camera/CameraSource.java)

The [CameraSource.Builder](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/blob/master/visionSamples/barcode-reader/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/vision/barcodereader/ui/camera/CameraSource.java) is tightly coupled with Detector like below

public Builder(Context context, Detector detector)

However, I prefer to accept `Detector` as a separate setter method - thay makes my life happier when it comes to testing. Also, I would like to modify open source code a little bit and package it in my existing custom SDK/library.

Am I allowed to modify it i.e renaming package, adding new methods etc. Off course I put same `Copyright (C) The Android Open Source Project` text on top of my new class. Does it causes any issues, when I commercialize my custom SDK?

Answer (score 1):

From below link, I got some details

https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html#redistribution

> 4. Redistribution. You may reproduce and distribute copies of the Work or Derivative Works thereof in any medium, with or without
>      modifications, and in Source or Object form, provided that You meet
>      the following conditions:
>
>    a.  You must give any other recipients of the Work or Derivative Works
>      a copy of this License; and
>
>    b.  You must cause any modified files to carry prominent notices
>      stating that You changed the files; and
>
>    c.  You must retain, in the Source form of any Derivative Works that
>      You distribute, all copyright, patent, trademark, and attribution
>      notices from the Source form of the Work, excluding those notices that
>      do not pertain to any part of the Derivative Works; and
>
>    d.  If the Work includes a "NOTICE" text file as part of its
>      distribution, then any Derivative Works that You distribute must
>      include a readable copy of the attribution notices contained within
>      such NOTICE file, excluding those notices that do not pertain to any
>      part of the Derivative Works, in at least one of the following places:
>      within a NOTICE text file distributed as part of the Derivative Works;
>      within the Source form or documentation, if provided along with the
>      Derivative Works; or, within a display generated by the Derivative
>      Works, if and wherever such third-party notices normally appear. The
>      contents of the NOTICE file are for informational purposes only and do
>      not modify the License. You may add Your own attribution notices
>      within Derivative Works that You distribute, alongside or as an
>      addendum to the NOTICE text from the Work, provided that such
>      additional attribution notices cannot be construed as modifying the
>      License.
>
> You may add Your own copyright statement to Your modifications and may
>   provide additional or different license terms and conditions for use,
>   reproduction, or distribution of Your modifications, or for any such
>   Derivative Works as a whole, provided Your use, reproduction, and
>   distribution of the Work otherwise complies with the conditions stated
>   in this License.